# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.wsgi'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

Trying to deploy my django application to elastic beanstalk using github actions but I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_pit.wsgi'`.

Edit: Added wsgi.py file & django.config.

The project is deploying correctly to aws but it is Degraded after deploy.

**Github Action:**

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Generate deployment package & zip
    run: zip -r deploy.zip . -x '*.git*'

  - name: Get timestamp
    uses: gerred/actions/current-time@master
    id: current-time

  - name: Run string replace
    uses: frabert/replace-string-action@master
    id: format-time
    with:
      pattern: '[:\.]+'
      string: "${{ steps.current-time.outputs.time }}"
      replace-with: "-"
      flags: "g"

  - name: Deploy to EB
    uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v20
    with:
      aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      application_name: project-pit
      environment_name: project-pit-cloud
      version_label: "app-${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}"
      region: ap-southeast-2
      deployment_package: deploy.zip

  - name: Deployed!
    run: echo App deployed to ELB
```

**django.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "project_pit.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "project_pit.wsgi:application"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```

**wsgi.py**

```
"""
WSGI config for project_pit project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_pit.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: 1) Did you create the file **project_pit.wsgi**? 2) Edit your question and show the contents of **.ebextensions/django.config**. 3) The **.wsgi** file initializes your application. Refer to this link:https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added my django.config file to the question. I don't have a file named project_pit.wsgi but I have a wsgi.py file under a folder called project_pit in my django directory is that the same thing?

Comment: Your **django.config** is specifying the file **project_pit.wsgi**. The **wsgi.py** is doing the same thing (same code). Rename it to **project_pit.wsgi**.

Comment: @JohnHanley Okay thanks, I’ll give it a go. Interestingly if I use ‘eb deploy’ from my terminal it works fine. any reason that it’s different when deploying using github actions?

Comment: I don't know why. Deploy with **eb deploy** and look at the files after deployment. Then do the same with GitHub and compare. Perhaps **eb deploy** is copying or transforming files.